# Pause and play Jquery timer using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have a timer running using jquery setInterval and a button that toggles between play and pause. I need the timer to pause and/or continue running when the user clicks on the play/pause button. Also, for some reason, the seconds goes from "59" to "01". It's skipping "00". I'm not sure why. Thanks for your help!

**HTML:**

```
<div id="clock">0:00</div>

<div id="audioBtn">
   <div class="btn play"></div>
   <div class="btn pause"></div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
var output = $('#clock');
var isPaused = false;
var min = 0;
var sec = 0;
var t = window.setInterval(function() {
    if(!isPaused) {
        sec++;
        if (sec < 10) {
            output.html(min + ":0" + sec);
        } else {
            output.html(min + ":" + sec);
        }
        if (sec === 59) {
            sec = 0;
            min++;
        }
    }
}, 1000);

if ($('.btn').hasClass('pause')) {
    $('#audioBtn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("should pause");
        isPaused = true;
    });
};

if ($('.btn').hasClass('play')) {
    $('#audioBtn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("should play");
        isPaused = false;
    });
};
```

Comment: That's javascript setInterval, not jqueryl :p

Comment: `for some reason, the seconds goes from "59" to "01". It's skipping "00".` e.g `if (sec === 59) {
  sec = -1;...}` because you use at top of interval callback `sec++;`

Answer (score 1):

change it to
        `if (sec == 59) {
            sec = -1;
            min++;
        }`

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply. I was wondering how to have the timer pause and then continue playing if the user clicks on the play/pause button again. I tried the code below but the timer doesn't continue when I click on the button after pausing it. $('#audioBtn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    clearTimeout();
    isPaused = true;
  });

Comment: the way you define methods for click event makes them run for both play and pause, you can check it on console. you should make two different methods for pause and play like this   `if ($('.btn').hasClass('pause')) {
 $('#audioBtn > div.btn.pause').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("should pause");
  isPaused = true;
 });
};

if ($('.btn').hasClass('play')) {
 $('#audioBtn > div.btn.play').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("should play");
  isPaused = false;
 });
};`